# Select MSVS build configuration when generating a buildsystem with CMake

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I have a multiplatform CMake project, and occasionally I have to build it manually for Windows. I generate a buildsystem like this:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G"Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64 ../path/to/source
```

Then I open `*sln` file and press F7 to build. It runs for 40 minutes, and after that I understand that I didn't select proper configuration in the combobox. It's annoying! When command line option was `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`, but combobox was set to `Debug`, build fails after spending a decent time.

Is it possible to generate an MSVS project with build configuration selected from command line?

Note that I'm aware of `msbuild` command and it's `-p:Configuration=xxxxx` flag. The question is about cases when for some reason you need to build from Visual Studio's GUI.

Comment: You can limit the supported configurations from the command line by adding `-DCMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES=Release`. Maybe that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the selected configuration for the GUI is not possible with CMake at this moment.

The main reason for this is that this information is stored in the `.suo` file generated by Visual Studio. CMake itself only generates the project and solution files, while the `.suo` file will be generated by Visual Studio itself.

Alternatively, use CMake's [command line build option](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#build-a-project) for this. After configuring your project and generating the VS `.sln` file from CMake as usual, simply run:

```
cmake --build <path_to_build_directory> --config Release
```

This works independently of the selected generator and is the most reliable way of building CMake projects.

Comment: It's the same as building with `msbuild` directly. My question was about building with GUI, as I noted in the last sentence.

Comment: @Sergey Not a duplicate after all, that question I was thinking of was a slightly different one. Still the command line is the closest thing I got to an answer. Edited to clarify that changing the GUI selection is not possible with CMake currently.